# Issue in Maven dependency when calling external jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I am facing an issue with the Maven packaging  my project is

1. Maven project called (A) that has two threads one will run Spring
   Boot App and one will run Normal java project
2. Maven project
   called (B) with Normal java  Code will have Pojo and Models classes
   used in all project
3. Maven project called (C) with Normal java
   Code
4. Maven Project Called (E) with Normal java code

To summarize the use of them

1. (A),(C),(E) will use Models/Pojo Classes from (B), (B) is added as Dependency in their POM
2. (A) will use Method from (C), (C) is added as Dependency in (A) POM
3. (C) will Load class from (E) using Classloader and use a method

**The issue here:**

when the (C) project Load a class in (E) and try to use a method with Parameter class from (B) {RestConnection beans} throw

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: B/beans/RestConnections
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.eska.module.execution.model.bo.ExecutionBo.openANDLoadAllJarsDest(ExecutionBo.java:468)
    at com.eska.module.execution.model.bo.ExecutionBo.getDestModelJarData(ExecutionBo.java:372)
    at com.eska.module.execution.model.service.impl.ExecutionServiceImpl.start(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:45)
    at com.eska.module.execution.MainExecution.MainExecution.main(MainExecution.java:94)
    at com.eska.med.provman.module.generation.model.bo.StartupThreadingPhases$InterruptableTask.run(StartupThreadingPhases.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: B/beans/RestConnections
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 9 more
```

**Note:**
The Project works fine if I run it from eclipse, but when I try to use the Maven jars this issue happened

I tried to export Runnable jar from the eclipse (the Project is added in the build path), this issue didn't happen but the spring boot will not work.

**Can anyone Help please?**

Comment: You probably haven't built a jar which includes dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that (B) is not on the classpath when you run your project. On the CLI you would need to add `-cp <path to (B) jar>`